# how to use or , and oparator in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying evaluting the expression but i am getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&" why it is coming i don't know can you help me any one please

I tried code:

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all your if's inside the parantheses, and double equal-chars:

```
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var A = 10, N = 6, D = 3, N = 0;
        $("#submit").click(function(){debugger;
        var q1 = $('input[name=q1]:checked').val();
        var q2 = $('input[name=q2]:checked').val();
        var q3 = $('input[name=q3]:checked').val();
            if((q1 == Agree || q1 == nuetral) && ((q1+q2+q3)/3 > 0.60)){
             console(q1 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% );
            }
            else if((q2 == Agree || q2 ==nuetral) && ((q1+q2+q3/3) > 0.60)){
             console(q2 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% );
            }
            else if((q3 == Agree || q3 == nuetral) && ((q1+q2+q3/3) > 0.60)){
             console(q3 Agree or Nuetral and also value is above 60% );
            }
            else{
                console(q1,q2 and q3 DisAgree or NotApplicable and also value is bellow 60% );
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: not working due to q1 and q2 q3 values are string i am not evealute expression

Comment: You have some confusion in your code, for example you store "agree" as a value, so `.val()` returns "agree", but then you try to add that to get a %age.   You can't use it this way.

Comment: This answer correctly answers the questions as to how to use or/and - the rest of the failed logic code is outside the scope of the question.